# Como faço para armazenar vários objetos em uma linha da tabela do banco usando Django

Tags: python, django, back-end

Estou fazendo um sistema de uma academia usando django, e nele eu quero adicionar um treino para cada cliente e quero dividir esse treino em músculos, então teria que adicionar vários exercícios para cada músculo. Exemplo: Dia 1- Costas - exercicio 1, exercicio 2. Porém eu quero fazer essa relação entre tabelas, pois criei uma tabela para musculos, outra para exercicios e outra para o treino (unindo as duas). E estou com dificuldades para adicionar vários exercícios na tabela treino.

**models.py**

```
class Musculo(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.nome

class Exercicio(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    musculos = models.ForeignKey(Musculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.nome

class Treino(models.Model):
    musculos = models.ForeignKey(Musculo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    exercicios = models.ForeignKey(Exercicio, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

````
class TreinoForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treino
        fields = ('musculos', 'exercicios')

```
````

Comment: Olá Igor! Recomendo que veja a parte Nested do Django!

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A relação de vários exercícios por musculo já foi feita na tabela Exercicio quando você criou a FK para musculos. Então você não precisa do campo exercício na tabela Treino. Se você quiser listar todos os exercicios de um musculo em um treino, basta fazer isso: `Treino.objects.get(musculo=nome_musculo).exercicio_set.all()`
2. Agora se a sua inteção é que o conjunto de exercicios por músculo seja diferente por treino. Então o campo musculo na tabela exercício não é necessário e a relação entre conjunto de exercícios e musculo se daria pela tabela Treino. Nesse caso, Se você quiser listar todos os exercicios de um musculo em um treino, você também poderia usar
   `Treino.objects.get(musculo=nome_musculo).exercicio_set.all()`
3. Se a sua intenção é trabalhar com vários formulários na mesma view. Use classe `FormSets` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).